# Android dual sim card detection

Tags: android, sim-card

After reading a lot of documentation, I understood that there is no official way to detect whether the android phone uses dual or just a single card, but obviously many apps are using that feature, so I decided to ask does anyone know how can I implement that?

Comment: Contact device manufacturers and see if they have some SDK add-on that allows you to detect the presence of second sim.